# Passing data from spinner to TextView depending on user selection

Tags: java, android

So I have a Spinner that contains 2 possible options. But i have only one TextView in other activity where the user selection will show.

The problem is, how do I set that in second activity? Tried numerous times with various if - statements, nothing worked.

Here's the code of my spinner

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (position == 0){

                            intent.putExtra("ciljJePovecanjeTezine", cilj.getSelectedItem().toString());

                        } else if (position == 1){
                            intent.putExtra("ciljJeMrsavljenje", cilj.getSelectedItem().toString());

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
```

and here's the second activity in which I want text to appear

```
String prehrana = intent.getStringExtra("ciljJePovecanjeTezine");
        String prehrana2 = intent.getStringExtra("ciljJeMrsavljenje");

        ciljPrehranaRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPrehranaCiljRezultat);

        ciljPrehranaRezultat.setText(prehrana);
        ciljPrehranaRezultat.setText(prehrana2);
```

Now how do I set that if user selects option one, option one shows in TextView and if user selects option two, option two appears?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you using two different keys?

Comment: Because there are two different options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a global String variable to save the spinner value and then send that to the other activity on press of a button (or whatever you are using to change activity). For example:

```
String spinnerValue;

public void onCreate(...){
...
spinnerValue = cilj.getSelectedItem().toString()
...
}

public void onItemSelected(...){
     spinnerValue = cilj.getSelectedItem().toString();
}


Intent intent = new Intent(THIS_ACTIVITY,OTHER_ACTIVITY.CLASS);
intent.putExtra("spinnerValue",spinnerValue);
startActivity...
```

Comment: getting NullPointerException at line spinnerValue = cilj.getSelectedItem().toString() in onCreate

Comment: this line is to be added AFTER the spinner has been initialized with its adapter.

Comment: Now the app works, but the TextView still shows only one value

Comment: Add a breakpoint in onItemSelected and check if the app is going there.

Comment: Just a point of terminology, Java does not have global variables.

Comment: Out of the scope of the function, I meant.